# How to snap windows to each other?

Tags: windows-10, macos, desktop, desktop-customization, window-manager

On Windows 10 its possible to snap an application window to (left/right) size or to the corners, one have just to drag the window there.

On macOS windows stick to each other, so its easier to position them exaclty side by size. Is it possible to achieve this on Windows 10?

Perhaps such a feature existed in the past (https://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace/snapping.html).

Comment: You need 3rd party software to add this feature. Windows itself does not include this function.

Comment: The Microsoft document [Snap your windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241) describes the ways to arrange all your open windows using the mouse, keyboard, or the Snap Assist feature. You can read it and see if this is what you need.

Comment: I would appreciate a suggestion of one or more of those "3rd party software to add this feature"